# Svn ignore some files in a directory

Tags: file, svn, directory, ignore

I would like to ignore `*.dll` and `*.xml` under `bin` directory, but include everything else (`*.dll.refresh`). I tried the following ignore patterns but that didn't work:

```
bin/*.dll bin/*.xml
bin\*.dll bin\*.xml
```

I don't want to ignore all `*.dll`, and obviously need the `bin` folder checked in.

Comment: Do you mind if we remove the "design-patterns" tag, since this question has nothing to do with OOP design patterns?

Comment: @Brady I didn't realize I added that tag - no, I don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `svn:ignore` property on `bin` directory itself. [Here is a link to some documentaion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3).

Comment: That means I have to set that on each of my bin folders. Isn't there a way to globally set the rule for all bin folders that dll's and xml's under them are ignored?

Comment: I am not familiar with such a way. You can always write a script that goes through your directory tree and set that `svn:ignore` property, you do not have to do it by hand.